# Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type

Tags: matlab, for-loop, indexing, struct

When I run the code below, I get the error "

> Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

" Any idea on how to fix it?

```
dots.nDots = 100;

for dots = 1:dots.nDots
    dots.x = (rand(1,dots.nDots));   
    dots.y = (rand(1,dots.nDots));
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
dots.nDots = 100;
```

creates the variable `dots` as a [structure array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) with a field `nDots`. However, you overwrite the variable dots when you begin your [for loop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html):

```
for dots = 1:dots.nDots
```

At this point, the variable `dots` becomes an integer value. When you then try to access the field `nDots` you get the error you see, because `dots` is no longer a structure with that field.

If you simply rename your loop variable, you will no longer get that error:

```
dots.nDots = 100;

for iDot = 1:dots.nDots
  dots.x = (rand(1, dots.nDots));   
  dots.y = (rand(1, dots.nDots));
end
```

However, it's not clear what you hope to accomplish with this loop. All this will do is repeatedly overwrite `dots.x` and `dots.y` with a new set of 100 random values each, 100 times over.

Comment: I want to assign random initial x and y coordinates to each dots. Would you recommend a more effective way to do it? thanks

Comment: @Kathia: I think you just wouldn't need the loop at all. The line `dots.x = rand(1, dots.nDots);` creates a vector of 100 random values uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. See [`rand`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) for more info.